# Can I create a policy to an AWS DynamoDB table based on non-key attribute value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I have a table like below:

```
UserId1 (partition key) | UserId2 (non-key attribute)
        "id_001"        |         "id_002"
```

I want the user to be able to update items if `User's ID = UserId1` or `User's ID = UserId2` . I found the policy below but it can only satisfy `User's ID = UserId1`. Is it possible to use another attribute as constraint?

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": [
    "dynamodb:GetItem",
    "dynamodb:PutItem",
    "dynamodb:Query",
    "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
   ],
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:dynamodb:REGION:123456789012:table/UserData"
   ],
   "Condition": {
    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
     "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
      "${graph.facebook.com:id}"
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no.

The non-key attribute is not defined in any meaningful place to allow AWS to come up with an arn for it. Without an arn, you can't create a policy for it.

I'm not sure if you can have policies based on an indexed attribute. Might be worth giving that a go?